# Can I modify the AccountContactRelations from the contact page?

Tags: accountcontactrelation

We are launching the AccountContactRelations in our org (mainly because it's better and triggerable)

Is there a way to manage/update the roles from within the Contact Edit page?

So, when I create a new contact, by default the account will become the primary account, but is it possible to add more roles to this contact for this specific account ?  (not to relate to other acocunts - that's obviously not possible IMO) ?

This way, upon creation of the new contact, already, all relevant roles will be setup, and no need to edit that record again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you cannot edit roles from the edit page of a Contact...at least not without a trigger.

It sounds like you don't quite understand what `AccountContactRelation` (ACR from here out) does.

ACR is a junction object (meaning it's in a master-detail relationship with both `Account` and `Contact`). While Salesforce will only automatically create an ACR record for the `Account` pointed to by `Contact`'s `AccountId` field, it is possible for you to create more ACR records yourself (either from the Account, or from a Contact).

The `Direct` checkbox for ACR is not writable. This is controlled by Salesforce, and whichever Account the Contact points to via `AccountId` becomes the "direct" relationship.

This shouldn't come as much of a surprise, because the name of the feature that enables ACR is "Allow Contacts to be related to multiple Accounts".

The ACR object contains a standard field, `Roles`, which is a multipicklist. You can select other roles for a given Account-Contact pair, but unless you have a trigger to help you on that, I believe this is something that you need to do manually.

Comment: Thank you, You helped with some clarification, but my initial questions stands, although, after some more reading, I think it's not possible. Unless I will write a new VF page, than can accept the required relations.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using Process Builder from Contact Object. In the Action ->Select Update records ->Select a record related to the Contact-> AccountContactRelations